# php registration validation error.

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP & stackoverflow. 
Just trying to do a registration form with email duplication check.
It works fine when trying to add a new user but the problem is when trying to update an existing user. "It says email already exist" How can I fix it i.e. if an existing user is trying to update his details it will not check for duplication
Below is my code:

```
case 'users':
        if(isset($_POST['submitted']) == 1) {

            $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['first']);
            $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['last']);
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['email']);

            if($_POST['password'] == '' OR $_POST['password2'] == '' OR $_POST['password'] != $_POST['password2']) {

                $message = '<p class="alert alert-danger">Both password field mus be filled & matching</p>';

            } if(strlen($_POST['password'])<6 OR strlen($_POST['password'])>20) {

                $message = '<p class="alert alert-danger">Password must be 6 to 20 characters</p>';
            }

            if ($first =='' OR $last =='') {

                $message = '<p class="alert alert-danger">How should we address you ?</p>';
            }


               $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
               $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q) or die(mysqli_error());
               if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0)
                        {
                $message = '<p class="alert alert-danger">This Email is already used.</p>';
               }

            if (empty($email) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

                $message = $message.'<p class="alert alert-danger">Please provide a valid email address  </p>';

            } 

                            if(isset($_POST['id']) != '') {

                $action = 'updated';
                $q = "UPDATE users SET first = '$first', last = '$last', email = '$_POST[email]', password = md5(SHA1('$_POST[password]')), status = $_POST[status] WHERE id = $_GET[id]";
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

            } else {

                $action = 'added';

                $q = "INSERT INTO users (first, last, email, password, status) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$_POST[email]', md5(SHA1('$_POST[password]')), '$_POST[status]')";

                if($message == '') {
                    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

                }

            }

            if ($message == '') {

                $message = '<p class="alert alert-success">User was '.$action.'!</p>';
            } 



        }

        if (isset($_GET['id'])){ $opened = data_user($dbc, $_GET['id']); }  

    break;
```

Comment: You probably should use a different route for updating details and leave this untouched. Also, a user should be allowed to update only if he/she's logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is `if(isset($_POST['id'])` but in your UPDATE query you use `WHERE id = $_GET[id]`.

Therefore an new entry is created which conflicts with the uniqueness of your email field.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it displays "This Email is already used." but updates the fields

The line

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0)
{
    $message = '<p class="alert alert-danger">This Email is already used.</p>';
}
```

Makes a messages if the email already exists. You have 2 with to remove the message.

1. add a condition like this :

.

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) &&  $_POST['id'] != '' && mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0 )
                    {
    $message = '<p class="alert alert-danger">This Email is already used.</p>';
}
```

2. remove the message if you update it a user :

.

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) &&  $_POST['id'] != '') {
    $action = 'updated';
    $q = "UPDATE users SET first = '$first', last = '$last', email = '$_POST[email]', password = md5(SHA1('$_POST[password]')), status = $_POST[status] WHERE id = $_GET[id]";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $message = '';
} else {
```

N.B: you got an error in your UPDATE condition. isset return true or false, so you have to do 2 different tests. (as I corrected in my 2nd solution)